# Issue on Parsing JSON from MySQL Database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

PHP json_encode() at following code:

```
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);
$query = "SELECT * FROM data limit 1" ;
$results = $con->query($query);
$return = array();
if($results) {
  while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
     $return[] = $row;
  }
}
echo json_encode($return);
$con->close();
```

creates a JSON object like this:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"tabo","age":"26","phone":"44444422","comments":""}]
```

can you please let me know how I can get rid of the `[]` at begiining and end of the JSON and have only

```
{"id":"1","name":"tabo","age":"26","phone":"44444422","comments":""}
```

at output? The reason that I need to do this is accessing the JSON object by using  the `jQuery.parseJSON()` which those `[]` make the properties undefined!

Thanks

Comment: since you're just selecting one single row, dont assign it inside an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting an array into a variable and turning it into an array. The JSON encode is saying that the object is an array with the `[]`.

You can get past this by doing the encode right on the spot:

```
if($results) {
  while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
     $json=json_encode($row);
  }
}
$con->close();

echo $json;
```

The encoded JSON you are echoing is basically telling you that the object you encoded is an array with all the bits inside it. What you are trying to do is to show the `$row` as a JSON, not the row inside an array.

Comment: thanks Fluffeh, to be honest I am still confused about json object and array! some of them starts and ends with [] and some just with {}! any way thanks for great help

Comment: by the way I still need 6 more minutes to accept the answer!